# How to code it in R that count the probability of succeed once at most in 10times at a Bernoulli which P=0.1

Tags: r, statistics

Count the probability of succeed once at most in 10 times at a Bernoulli which P=0.1 I've tried by myself:

```
pbinom(0,10,.1)
```

I don't know it is right or not, as I don't know if "at most" here is the same the "at least".

Answer (score 1):

Having at most one success means that you can have either zero success or one success.

If X is the number of successes, then the probability of having at most 1 success is p(X<=1)=p(X=0)+p(X=1).

In R, the function giving the probability p(X=x) is the density function `dbinom`.

So you want to do `dbinom(0,10,0.1)+dbinom(1,10,0.1)`